# redis: EVAL and the TIME

Tags: time, lua, redis, eval

I like the Lua-scripting for redis but i have a big problem with TIME.

I store **events in a SortedSet**.

The **score is the time**, so that in my application i can view all events in given time-window.

```
redis.call('zadd', myEventsSet, TIME, EventID);
```

Ok, but this is not working - i can not access the TIME (Servertime).

Is there any way to get a time from the Server without passing it as an argument to my lua-script? Or is passing the time as argument the best way to do it?

Comment: meanwhile there is TIME. With some lua you can wrap that around zadd. `127.0.0.1:6379> eval "local t = (redis.call('time')); return t[1]" 0
"1438894559"`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is explicitly forbidden (as far as I remember). The reasoning behind this is that your lua functions must be deterministic and depend only on their arguments. What if this Lua call gets replicated to a slave with different system time?

**Edit (by Linus G Thiel):** This is correct. From the [redis EVAL docs](http://redis.io/commands/eval):

> ### Scripts as pure functions
>
> A very important part of scripting is writing scripts that are pure functions. Scripts executed in a Redis instance are replicated on slaves by sending the script -- not the resulting commands.
>
> [...]
>
> In order to enforce this behavior in scripts Redis does the following:
>
> - Lua does not export commands to access the system time or other external state.
> - Redis will block the script with an error if a script calls a Redis command able to alter the data set after a Redis random command like RANDOMKEY, SRANDMEMBER, TIME. This means that if a script is read-only and does not modify the data set it is free to call those commands. Note that a random command does not necessarily mean a command that uses random numbers: any non-deterministic command is considered a random command (the best example in this regard is the TIME command).

There is a wealth of information on why this is, how to deal with this in different scenarios, and what Lua libraries are available to scripts. I recommend you read the whole documentation!